# Rotate node to look at target (SceneKit)

Tags: scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to make a node rotate along the X axis to look at another node.

I tried using the SCNLookAtConstraint with the gimbal turned off, but this still allows the node to rotate on both the X and Y axes. (Also, it makes the rear of the node face the target, not the front.)

How do I calculate how to rotate one node to face another from two vector 3 positions?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnlookatconstraint) talk about the orientation of a node, and what it means to 'look' at another node:

> A node points in the direction of the negative z-axis of its local coordinate system. This axis defines the view direction for nodes containing cameras and the lighting direction for nodes containing spotlights or directional lights, as well as the orientation of the node’s geometry and child nodes. When Scene Kit evaluates a look-at constraint, it updates the constrained node’s transform property so that the node’s negative z-axis points toward the constraint’s target node.

You can modify that by specifying a different value for `constraint.localFront`, such as `SCNVector3(0,0,1)` to point with the positive z-axis instead of the negative.

If you need more control over which axis you want to engage, then you have a couple of options.

1. Create an invisible target node that remains positioned along the plane perpendicular to your rotation axis
2. Instead of using constraints, use [SCNNode.look(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2867394-look) to update the node within your game loop, providing a translated target coordinate along the perpendicular plane.

If the target is the camera, then checkout [SCNBillboardConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnbillboardconstraint), which allows you to specify which axes are free to rotate:

```
let billBoard = SCNBillboardConstraint()
billBoard.freeAxes = [.X]
node.constraints = [billBoard]
```